# error while using SQLITE on android

Tags: android, sqlite

hi i am trying to create a DB and then setting text view value based on the value returned from the database. i am getting an error "SYNTAX ERROR(code1) "
here is my code.

```
`package com.example.dbex;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.sql.SQLPermission;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contactsmanager";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS="contacts";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER="number";
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE"+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_NAME+"TEXT,"+KEY_NUMBER+"TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addContact(Contacts contacts)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contacts.getname());
        values.put(KEY_NUMBER, contacts.getnumber());
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Contacts getContact(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_NUMBER},KEY_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        if(c!=null)
        {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        Contacts contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
        return contacts;
    }

    public void deleteContact(Contacts contacts)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID+"=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contacts.getID())});
        ``db.close();
    }


}
`
```

please help me rectify my mistake in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space after the "create table" and "drop table if exists":

```
"create table "
"drop table if exists "
```

Comment: thanks. i have done that but i am now getting an error saying that there is "no such column named 'id' and 'number' " ?

Comment: You need more spaces, it looks like you're creating a table with a column called IDINTEGER

Comment: thanks, i have fixed the errors caused due to the spaces. but now i am getting an error "cursor index out of bounds" on this line ` Contacts contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));`

Answer (score 1):

You need a space in the SQL in your `onUpgrade` method:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Currently the executed SQL is:
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTScontacts`

It needs to be:
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts`

This also applies to a few places in your `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_NUMBER+" TEXT"+")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
}
```

Something which helps me track down errors like this is to add a try/catch block and throw your own exception which includes the generated SQL, e.g.:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_NUMBER+" TEXT"+")";
try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
} catch (SQLException sqlException) {
throw new SQLException("Error executing SQL: '" + CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS + "', message: " + sqlException.getMessage(), sqlException);
}
    }
```

This allows you to see the error message as well as the SQL which caused it. If you do this it's recommended to create your own `execSQL` method which includes this code. You could even create your own wrapper around `SQLiteDatabase` and add this logic to your own overridden `execSQL`.

Comment: thanks, i have fixed the errors caused due to the spaces. but now i am getting an error "cursor index out of bounds" on this line `  Contacts contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));`